# Ruby on Rails : Create user profile in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using `devise` gem. So, I can easily edit current user account by generating `devise views`. I've already a model `user` and it's related to `devise` gem for authenticating purpose. Now, I want to show `user profile` or `user information` in a single page. I can do it by creating a new controller. But, is it efficient or recommended way to do that??

Answer (score 2):

Ryan Bates has a [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) that explains how to do this. Essentially, you make use of nested attributes for the models.

Answer (score 1):

There's no performance penalty for creating another controller, all it does is help you organize your code. Here's how I did it:

```
**controller**
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

end

**routes**
  devise_for :users, 
  resources :users, :only => [:show]
```